# How can I use AJAX to return all of the "name" values in my JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a JSON file consisting of nine complete record sets, below i have listed three.

my end goal is to add AJAX to a website, the information from my json file is currently listed directly into the html rather than through AJAX. I extracted and built the JSON file for using it through AJAX instead.

I would like to understand how i should go about iterating through each json object and return each "name" listed.

```
[{
   "name":"Keith Moore",
   "link":"http://www.moorelife.org/freedownloads-serieslist.php?",
   "image":"keith_moore.jpg",
   "details":"Teacher/Pastor, I refer to Keith as my \"bible college experience,\" he has 30+ years of free audio and video available on any and every subject."
 },
  {
   "name":"Kenneth Hagin",
   "link":"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIXcY2izjpDgROo3MRlAU2MJSyjthXLLc",
   "image":"kenneth_hagin.jpg",
   "details":"Prophet, with nearly 70 years of ministry under his belt, Hagin most commonly preached on the subject of faith in Gods word."
 },
  {
   "name":"Bill Johnson",
   "link":"https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLEtP4XPKdli585uNfIU8WNRYawCusmEYK",
   "image":"bill_johnson.jpg",
   "details":"Apostle/Pastor, Bill pastors a church in Redding California named Bethel Church, the church is most known for miracles, signs and wonders."
}]
```

so far this is what i have, but it doesnt go deep enough to access the names values

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $.getJSON("data/asdf.json", function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i, field) {
      $("#update").append(field + " ");
    });
  });
});
```

its reporting the following to my html:

[object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object] [object Object]

what I am looking for is a starting block of information that will allow me to begin building functions for each value listed in my JSON file.

Comment: All you want to do is output the `name` field of each object? You are very close to that. In the function you pass `each`, `field` is an object. you can access the `name` property like this: `field.name`. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code is accessing the Object, instead of the `name` property.

> ```
> $("#update").append(field + " ");
> ```

Change it to:

```
$("#update").append(field.name + " ");
```